# Regenerating data provided by Angular factories after source change

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I simplified my application to this example, so I know this particular case can be done more easier but I wanted to keep the app's original structure.

So, here I have a rootScope set at the beginning (this mock the data source from the original app):

```
.run(function($rootScope){
  $rootScope.initarray = [1,1];
})
```

There are two factories:

The `priceFactory` returns $rootScope.initarray in an asynchronous way.

The `doublePrice` factory takes the array from priceFactory and doubles every item.

```
.factory('priceFactory', function ($rootScope, $q, $timeout) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $timeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve($rootScope.initarray)
      }, 1000);
    console.log('priceFactory');
    return deferred.promise;
})

.factory("doublePrice", function (priceFactory) {
  console.log('doublePrice');
  return priceFactory.then(
    function(data){
      var temp = [];
      for (i in data){
        temp.push(data[i]*2)
      }
      return temp;
    });
})
```

I also having two ui-route states, one showing the data returned by doublePrice, the second state having a button that adds a new element to `$rootScope.initarray`.

My problem is that when I add a new element to $rootScope.initarray in the second state, i have to update the data shown in the first state.

[Here's a codepen example about the issue.](http://codepen.io/neptune01/pen/JXWbrJ)

So, the question: if there is any simple way to achieve that update. I'm using angular with ionic, it's not a cache issue, but the factories and ui-router state resolve that returns the same data during the app run.

Comment: As you are making a copy of the `$rootScope.initarray` in `doublePriceFactory` by copying the values into `temp` array so that's why you need to update data in both states separately. You can solve it either by using object references and hence by updating the data only in one state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage `factory` service suggests that the returning value is cached on the first injection and reused on the subsequent injections. This is the desired behaviour and it can't be changed.

The need to get a fresh promise on each route change is the common case for route resolvers. The alternative is to use `factory` service that returns a function:

```
.factory('priceFactory', function ($rootScope, $timeout) {
  return function () {
    // no deferred antipattern is necessary here
    return $timeout(function() {
        return $rootScope.initarray;
    }, 1000);
  };
});
```

So it can be used like that (good if additional parameters from `$state` should be provided to a function):

```
priceResolver: function (priceFactory) {
  return priceFactory();
}
```

Or it can be `service` service, which is a perfect use case for resolvers, because it issues a new instance on each injection. `service` services get their instance as `this` but they can ignore it and return a new object instead:

```
.service('priceService', function ($rootScope, $timeout) {
  return $timeout(function() {
      return $rootScope.initarray;
  }, 1000);
});
```